# `man ascii` is misaligned when using vim as a pager

Tags: vim, man, pager

To use Vim as a pager for man I have

```
export MANPAGER="/usr/share/vim/vim73/macros/manpager.sh"
```

in my profile. Now man pages look very good with colors and stuff. However, when trying `man ascii` as a way of looking at the ASCII table, I notice that the table is mis-aligned as in the screenshot below:

[image: Messed up ASCII table]

This problem doesn't happen to the default pager. When I set `export MANPAGER="view -"` the table is also correct, so something must be wrong with the `manpager.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/sh
sed -e 's/\x1B\[[[:digit:]]\+m//g' | col -b | \
vim \
    -c 'let no_plugin_maps = 1' \
    -c 'set nolist nomod ft=man' \
    -c 'let g:showmarks_enable=0' \
    -c 'runtime! macros/less.vim' -
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: It works for me (Vim 7.1pl314 on Debian lenny or 7.2pl330 on Ubuntu 10.04, `C` or `en_US` or `en_US.UTF-8` locale, in xterm). What are your locale settings? In what terminal are you running this, and do other terminals make a difference? What is your version of Vim, what options was it compiled with? Does disabling your `.vimrc` with `vim -u /dev/null` make a difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I try with the following script things are normal:

```
#!/bin/sh
sed -e 's/\x1B\[[[:digit:]]\+m//g' | \
vim \
    -c 'let no_plugin_maps = 1' \
    -c 'set nolist nomod ft=man' \
    -c 'let g:showmarks_enable=0' \
    -c 'runtime! macros/less.vim' -
```

I'm not sure what role `col` plays in the sequence, but it is certainly messing up the spaces. Until somebody gives a better solution, this will be my fix.

**Edit**: so `col` was the problem because it "replaces white-space characters with tabs where possible". To fix this tell `col` to use spaces instead of tabs with the `-x` option. The final config is as follow (with credit to Gilles).

```
#!/bin/sh
sed -e 's/\x1B\[[[:digit:]]\+m//g' | col -bx | \
vim \
    -c 'let no_plugin_maps = 1' \
    -c 'set nolist nomod ft=man' \
    -c 'let g:showmarks_enable=0' \
    -c 'runtime! macros/less.vim' -
```

Comment: I wrote my comment on your question before I saw your answer. So maybe the version or configuration of `col` is the culprit. `col` replaces spaces with tabs, so it's easy to see why it would influence column alignment. I don't know what could have gone wrong though.

Comment: @Gilles Where is the configuration file for `col`? I looked in `/etc/` but no file name starts with "col".

Comment: Now that I think of it, there shouldn't be any configuration for `col` (neither compile-time nor run-time). [`col` was standardized in earlier versions of Single Unix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcu/col.html). Does `col -bx` solve the problem? What about `col -bp`?

Comment: @Gilles `col -bx` works (`col -bp` does not)! Do you want to make that another answer?

Comment: You thought the problem might be `col`, so just edit your answer.